# Aplicar css inscrutado en entradas de wordpress desde el panel de administración

Tags: html, css, wordpress

desde el panel de administración de wordpress. en una entrada usando la pestaña "html" tengo asi el código css.

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;color: #4517c6;">3. Reconciliación</h3>
```

y no coge el color, directamente no aparece el h3. Le he dado a actualizar al post para guardar los cambios, en una pagina de prueba el código css funciona me centra el h3 y le da el color azul pero en el blog no va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en el editor la pre visualización es correcta y luego no se ve en el blog casi seguro que el problema esta en el CSS. Puede que tengas una clase que superpone el estilo.

Haz lo siguiente. En el blog, presiona boton derecho del mouse y luego en ver código fuente. Busca la palabra ***3. Reconciliación***.

Si aparece efectivamente tenes un problema con los estilos CSS. En caso de que no aparezca lo mas probable es que no estes visualizando la pagina que estas editando.

Se pueden forzar los estilos en css. También puedes probar lo siguiente.

`<h3 style="text-align: center;color: #4517c6 !important;">3. Reconciliación</h3>`